# How do you use a 'just-defined' hash value in your next hash value

Tags: ruby, hash, hashtable

If I'm creating a hash:

```
h = {
  a: 5,
  b: a + 1
}
```

how do I use the value of `a` to define a value for `b` in ruby syntax?

Comment: Why not set the `:b` key after the hash is created?

Comment: This makes no sense. If the value is a constant, you can simply hard code it. If it is a variable created prior to hash creation, simply use it.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a ruby trick or not. Sometimes ruby is weird like that. If there isn't a trick, I can resort back to just doing a standard variable definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use a temp variable:

```
h = {
  a: x = 5,
  b: x + 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
h = {a: 5}.tap{|h| h[:b] = h[:a] + 1}
# => {:a=>5, :b=>6}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just do it the old fashioned way without resorting to any cute tricks:

```
h = {}
h[:a] = 5
h[:b] = h[:a] + 1

puts h #=> {:a => 5, :b => 6}
```